# How do I hide the activity indicator once there is no more data to load?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, tableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am paginating data from Firestore and I am able to get that to work.

Here is the paginating query:

```
if restaurantArray.isEmpty {
                query = db.collection("Restaurant_Data").limit(to: 4)
            } else {
                query = db.collection("Restaurant_Data").start(afterDocument: lastDocument!).limit(to: 4)
            }

query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("\(err.localizedDescription)")
            } else if querySnapshot!.isEmpty {
                self.fetchMore = false
                return
            } else {
                if (querySnapshot!.isEmpty == false) {
                    let allQueriedRestaurants = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap { (document) -> Restaurant in (Restaurant(dictionary: document.data(), id: document.documentID)!)}
                    guard let location = self.currentLocation else { return }
                    self.restaurantArray.append(contentsOf: self.applicableRestaurants(allQueriedRestaurants: allQueriedRestaurants, location: location))
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.fetchMore = false
                    })
                    self.lastDocument = querySnapshot!.documents.last
                    }
                }
            }
```

The pagination is triggered when the user drags the table view up:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let off = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let off1 = scrollView.contentSize.height

        if off > off1 - scrollView.frame.height * leadingScreensForBatching{
            if !fetchMore { // excluded reachedEnd Bool
                if let location = self.currentLocation {
                    queryGenerator(searched: searchController.isActive, queryString: searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased(), location: location)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also added an activity indicator to the bottom and that works as expected. Here is the code for that:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
        let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1
        if indexPath.section ==  lastSectionIndex && indexPath.row == lastRowIndex {
            // print("this is the last cell")
            let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .medium)
            spinner.startAnimating()
            spinner.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(44))

            tableView.tableFooterView = spinner
            tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

However, once the bottom of the table view is reached and there is no more data available, the indicator is still showing and I dont know how to get it to not show.

I tried using a variable to check if the Firestory query is done but my implementation is probably wrong so I cannot get it to work.

Comment: You should add the loading indicator in scrollViewDidScroll method if there is data to fetch and hide it at the beginning of the data response completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the moment when there is no more data available, you set the tableView footer view to nil or hidden = true, see below

```
tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
```

or

```
tableView.tableFooterView = nil
```

before you call `self.tableView.reloadData()`

If you do not know it, see code below

```
query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in

        if let err = err {
            print("\(err.localizedDescription)")
        } else if querySnapshot!.isEmpty {
            // Here you know when there is no more data
            self.fetchMore = false
            self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil // or self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        } else {
            if (querySnapshot!.isEmpty == false) {
                let allQueriedRestaurants = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap { (document) -> Restaurant in (Restaurant(dictionary: document.data(), id: document.documentID)!)}
                guard let location = self.currentLocation else { return }
                self.restaurantArray.append(contentsOf: self.applicableRestaurants(allQueriedRestaurants: allQueriedRestaurants, location: location))
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.fetchMore = false
                })
                self.lastDocument = querySnapshot!.documents.last
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way to determine if there is no more data i.e. no more documents in the collection or the query?